# Is it possible to make use of mspn service without registering to app hub for testing my app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am about to develop a windows phone app that makes use of mspn service. I haven't registerd to app hub. Is it possible to make use of mspn service without registering to app hub for testing my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so. (At least I remember testing this back in June 2010 - before registration was open.)

Have you tried?
There's nothing in the notification process which requires any reference to anything to do with your app hub registration, unless you need SSL or very large volume but you can easily test wihtout these.